# Confusion regarding trigonometry identity and mathematic operation

Tags: trigonometry

For this equation $$\cos\theta=-\cos\theta\tag{0}$$
normally one will just move the right hand side formula to left and getting $2\cos\theta=0$, so $\theta=\frac{\pi}{2}$.

However, if going the long way by expressing

$$-\cos\theta=(-1)\cos\theta+0=\cos(\pi)\cos\theta+\sin(\pi)\sin\theta=\cos(\pi-\theta) \tag1$$
and also
$$-\cos\theta=(-1)\cos\theta-0=\cos(\pi)\cos\theta-\sin(\pi)\sin\theta=\cos(\pi+\theta) \tag2$$

Isn't that from these equations will be getting

$$\cos\theta=\cos(\pi-\theta) \tag{1'}$$ and also
$$\cos\theta=\cos(\pi+\theta) \tag{2'}$$

So the first one will get
$$\theta=\frac{\pi}{2} \tag{1''}$$
but the second one
$$\pi=0 \tag{2''}$$
Where does it goes wrong?

Comment: Your mistake is that for $\cos(\theta)=\cos(\pi+\theta)$ you get the **same** solutions as $\cos(\theta)=\cos(\pi-\theta)$ because $\cos(\pi-\theta)=\cos(\pi+\theta)$ fpr all $\theta$. Thus $\theta=0$ is **not** a solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function $ \cos$ has not only one zero !

We have $ \cos \theta =0 \iff$ there is $k \in \mathbb Z$ such that $ \theta = \frac{2k+1}{2} \pi.$

Comment: Thank for pointing out my mistake , so $-cos\theta=cos((2k+1)\pi-\theta)$ and from first equation $cos\theta=cos((2k+1)\pi-\theta)$ produce the same result as $\theta=\frac{2k+1}{2}\pi$ but isn't $-cos\theta=cos((2k+1)\pi+\theta)$ also true? From first equation $cos\theta=cos((2k+1)\pi+\theta)$ getting $k\pi=0$? this is where I confuse.

Comment: Since $\cos$ is $2 \pi$ - periodic, we have: $\cos((2k+1)\pi+\theta)= \cos(\pi+ \theta+2k \pi)=\cos(\pi+ \theta) =- \cos \theta.$

Comment: sorry, there an error on my first comment in last sentence, meant to say $(2k+1)\pi=0$. so from your second comment and refer to 1st equation $cos\theta=-cos\theta=cos((2k+1)\pi+\theta)$ will be getting $(2k+1)\pi=0$ which is not make sense, in mathematics do we just ignore such equation while taking only $cos\theta=cos((2k+1)\pi-\theta)$?